# How to turn off record highlight feature?

Tags: overwatch

How to turn off [record highlight feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXHTSSl6zBA)?
I believe it records everything in the background, and then, when I press the button it cuts part of that recording, right? But that background recording should reduce my fps and I would like to get rid of it. How to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't turn off Overwatch highlights.

It actually doesn't seem to record full footage in the background from what I understand. Apparently, the Highlight feature can produce footage at a higher resolution and frame rate than your system can provide. This leads me to believe that instead of recording the complete screen in the background, it actually retains a deterministic representation of the past 12 seconds. When you decide you want to use one of your 3 highlight slots, it just stores this 12 second representation and doesn't actually change it to a video until you ask it to, using the settings you provided. So the highlights feature shouldn't actually have a noticeable effect on your system performance.

In addition, the highlight recording happens on the servers, so it shouldn't have any impact on your PC performance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your computer doesn't even record the game state; it doesn't even have the complete game state at any given time.  Only the server has the complete game state, and it's already recording the state for the entire game in order to create the play of the game.  Highlights, both manual and auto-generated, are created from this master game state recording.